# Chrome extension: Slide out menu from the left of Chrome window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible add a functionality in the extension that when you mouse over the left edge of Chrome window a menu with some options (what options is not important now) will slide out?

Answer (score 0):

no, Chrome does not have API to show such panel or handle such kind of event. The only possible workaround is to add you own div to left side of each webpage and show such pane as part of the webpage